# Detection code not working

Tags: excel, vba

I have a piece of code that uses port codes to identify a trade region. For the most part it works fine, but one of the exceptions isn't identifying properly.

In essence, when the trade is `EU-NA` and the destination is in the Caribbean (held in a slash-delimited list in `Range("RegionNACar")`) it should select `" to NA EC"` as a suffix (`sSufTo`). The only exception is if the origin port is `"ESSDR"`, in which case it should revert to the default suffix of `" to NA GL"` (which successfully identifies earlier).

The main function in use is `Contains_Keyword`, which is used extensively throughout the rest of the module and generally works fine:

```
Function Contains_Keyword(sDescr As String, sKeywords As String) As Boolean
    Dim A() As String, bIsIn As Boolean, i As Integer
    A = Split(sKeywords, "/")
    bIsIn = False
For i = LBound(A) To UBound(A)
    If InStr(1, sDescr, A(i)) Then
        bIsIn = True
        Exit For
    Else
        End If
Next i
Contains_Keyword = bIsIn
End Function
```

This is called by this line (mostly used without `.Value`, but I added it to see if it'd help):

```
If sTrade = "EU-NA" And Contains_Keyword(UCase(sPODCo), Range("RegionNACar").Value) _
    And Not (UCase(sPOL) = "ESSDR") Then sSufTo = " to NA EC"
```

I've set a watch both on `Range("RegionNACar").Value` in the sub itself and on `sKeywords` within the function; while it fetches the right data in the watch, `sKeywords` ends up fetching the data from `Range("RegionSAEC")`, stored in the cell above it. I've checked the range names and references, and they're all correct.

Can anyone spot what's wrong? I must be overlooking something, but I can't for the life of me figure out *what*...

Answer (score 0):

Well, it doesn't explain what's going wrong or give me a nice elegant single-line solution, but I've used this workaround for now:

```
If sTrade = "EU-NA" And Contains_Keyword(UCase(sTo), Range("RegionNACar").Value) Then sSufTo = " to NA EC"
If UCase(sPOL) = "ESSDR" Then
    If Contains_Keyword(UCase(sTo), Range("RegionNACar")) Then sSufTo = " to NA GL"
End If
```

It's not as clean, but it works. (As far as I can tell, for now.)